# Difference from angular $http and ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, cors

I'm developing and app with AngularJs. All works fine, and I test it on a webserver where I put the php include for $http request.
Now I've to create a website to support this app, and I use same php file but make call with jquery+ajax.
Why for the same calling, with ajax, I return

HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

This is my angula code:

```
 $scope.doLogin = function() {
      $http.post('/app/include/login.asp?username='+$scope.loginData.username+'&password='+$scope.loginData.password, $scope.loginData).success(function(data){
          if (data.error == ''){$state.go("app.bentornato");$localstorage.set('name', data.name);$localstorage.set('user_id', data.id);$localstorage.set('position', data.position);$localstorage.set('avatar',data.avatar);$rootScope.avatar = data.avatar} else {$ionicLoading.show({template: "Hai inserito dati errati!", duration: 1000})};
          }).error(function(data, status){$scope.errors.push(status);});
```

and this is my jquery code:

```
function exeLogin(){
    var nam=$("#USERNAME").val();
    var pas=$("#PASSWORD").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/app/include/login.asp",
        data: "username="+nam+"&password="+pas,
        success: function(data){alert(data)},
        error: alert("Errore connessione!")
        });
}
```

I also put in web.config the Access-Control-Allow-Origin value="*" and in login.asp response.addHeader "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"!
Why with angular works fine and with jquery not?!

Comment: Take 2 complete raw HTTP requests and compare them.

Answer (score 0):

`$http.post` is making a `POST` request while your `$.ajax` is making a `GET` request, this is probably the reason for the Method Not Allowed error.

An Angular equivalent to your jQuery call would be `$http.get(url)`

However, you should not use `GET` requests to send credentials (or have them in the url with `POST` requests) as they may be stored in access logs. If you own the server, you should get information about how to accept POST requests. Otherwise, ask your server admin.